# Fedora 24 (kernel 4.7.2.201) crash on boot once virtualbox guest additions have been installed

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, crash

I installed a new fedora24 (XFCe, 64bits) on the latest VirtualBox (5.0.26).
Works fine. 
I then update the kernel (to kernel 4.7.2.201). Reboot. Works fine.
I then intsall guest adiitions (5.0.26). Reboot. Crash during boot. (see Bug 1373424 on redhat.bugzilla).
Then I tried to reboot with previous kernel version. Works fine. 
Install guest additions (on old kernel), reboot. Works fine.

So, to be very clear, the issue is not to install Guest Additions, but to prevent the next boot of the Virtual machine from crashing when Guest Additions are installed.

Conclusion : **there is a (reproductible) incompatibility between latest Fedora 24 (4.7.2.201), and VirtualBox Guest Additions.** And by the way, the same happens exactly with Fedora23 (kernel 4.7.2.101)

I posted a bug to fedora bugzilla (Bug 1373424), but the bug was rejected as they (logically) do not care about the guests additions they don't control.

Anyone was faced with such issue ? 
Any options other than to not install "Guests Additions" which I need to increase screen resolution  ?

Many thanks !

PS : Hosts is W10-64bits-i7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to VirtualBox v5.1.4 which has a bugfix for 4.7.x kernels. But, if you are using the kmod-VirtualBox-additions from rpmfusion you must wait for an updated rpm. The maintainer is working on it.

https://bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4239

Comment: That was exactly the issue ! Thanks for pointing it out. It now works like a charm ...